# For given condition, find 2x+3y-4z

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integers

$x, y\ and\ z$ are three positive integers which satisfy the relation:

$$x+\frac{1}{y+\frac{1}{z+1}} = 5.8$$

Find $2x+3y-4z$

In this question, I cannot get how to proceed, since theres only one equation and three unknowns! But some algebraic manipulation may lead to correct answer, but I can't figure out for very long time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$5.8=5+\dfrac45=5+\dfrac1{\dfrac54}=5+\dfrac1{1+\dfrac14}$$

Comment: Thank you a lot, now we can compare and fin the solution right?

Comment: @marekjon Just to be clear. You start by saying that $y,z\ge 1$ implies that $\frac{1}{y+\frac{1}{z+1}}<1$. $x$ is a positive integer, so we must have $x=5$. Now you have $y+\frac{1}{z+1}=1.25$. And so on.